# oracle.jbo.InvalidObjNameException: JBO-25005: <some pagedef>of type Iterator Binding Definition is invalid

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a adf application and on visiting to a page this exception is coming.
Its coming randomly and upon searching on google not getting any specific solution. Sometimes its coming on table row selection, sometimes its on clicking a button. Please suggest what is the cause and how to fix it.

Exception like: 
oracle.jbo.InvalidObjNameException: JBO-25005: Object name oracle_jbo_uicli_binding_JUIteratorBinding_281 of type Iterator Binding Definition is invalid.

Comment: Tell us your jdev version, please!

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by adding attribute EnableTokenValidation="false" in pagedef file.